# PUT method in Node.js/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, put

I'm having issues with a simple PUT method in Node.js (MongoDB collection.update). Any help would be appreciated. At this point, I'm not getting an error, just an empty response.

index.js:

```
app.put('/UpdateValues/:collection/:entity', function(req, res) {
   var params = req.params;
   var entity = params.entity;
   var collection = params.collection;

   var value1 = req.body.value1;
   var value2 = req.body.value2;

   if (entity) {
       collectionDriver.updateValues(collection, entity, value1, value2, function(error, objs) {
          if (error) { res.status(400).send(error); }
          else { res.status(200).send(objs); }
       });
   } else {
      res.send(400, {error: 'bad url', url: req.url});
   }
});
```

collectionDriver.js:

```
CollectionDriver.prototype.updateValues = function(collectionName, nameDoc, value1new, value2new, callback) { 
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
        if (error) callback(error);
        else {

            the_collection.update(
               { name: nameDoc },
               { $set: {
                   value1: value1new,
                   value2: value2new
                }},
                function( err, result ) {
                        if ( err ) throw err;
                    }
                );

        }
    });
};
```

Testing with:

$ curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"value1":"1","value2":"1"}' http://localhost/UpdateValues/collection/test

Comment: The `callback` you are passing in is never being referenced on success. Also `.update()` does not return the modified document. You probably want `.findOneAndUpdate()` if you expect the modified response.

Comment: thanks Blakes!  The values are updating, just the callback isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

Reference the callback you are passing in within your function. Presently you do not. You also seem like you are expeting the modified document in response, so you need [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead:

```js
CollectionDriver.prototype.updateValues = function(collectionName, nameDoc, value1new, value2new, callback) { 
  this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
    if (error) callback(error);

    the_collection.findOneAndUpdate(    // <-- new method
      { name: nameDoc },
      { $set: {
        value1: value1new,
        value2: value2new
      }},
      { returnOriginal: false },        // <-- tells to return modified document
      callback                          // <--- passes to callback you passed in
    );

  });
});
```